# How to structure properly Firebase Database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

I read some Firebase database structure guides on how to structure your data properly (without data nesting) but I have one question. 
So, I have an iOS app that uses Firebase database. The users need to login/register. 
In terms of data structure, my database looks like this:

```
-Database
---Users
-----User1
--------username: johndoe
---------email: johndoe@test.com
---------display_name: John Doe
-----User2 {....}
-----User3 {....}
```

Now, let's imagine I have 100K users in there. Every time a new user is being registered, I check if the username & the email already exist in the database, if they don't then create the new user account.

My question is - Do I need to create a new object that contains only the usernames and another that contains only the emails? I'm asking this because I'm concerned that if I iterate through the Users objects I will potentially be downloading hundreds of megabytes just to check if the username and the email already exist.

Comment: Make 2 new nodes, in which all usernames and emails are stored. Next, make a firebase database rule in which !data.exists() is presented in the write function. This way: users dont download data at all & it is 100% secured and their is no way a duplicate username can exists. Your method is not good: download data -> check for exists -> upload username. Since it is asynchronous, there can be 2 same usernames.

Comment: That comment is not accurate and having two usernames has *nothing* to do with Firebase being asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase will not allow duplicate users (authentication names). So when you call createUser, firebase will return an error if the user already exists.

Secondly, if you are performing a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) for a specific item in Firebase, you are not downloading anything unless that item is found. So whether its 10 or 100k user nodes, nothing is downloaded when performing a query other than the nodes that match the query, which would only be one if there was a duplicate user. again though, this is not needed since Firebase rejects duplicate authentication names.

And to clarify; there is nothing wrong with nesting nodes. However, keeping them flat is usually better *depending on your use case*. So don't go overcomplicating your structure if you don't need to.

Oh, and your Firebase structure is spot on. Keep going with that.

Comment: OK, I got a bit confused with all the comments and people saying different things. But your answer kind of make sense. And based on it, I don't change anything when it comes to the way my database is structured right now. So, when createUser is being called, I'm not downloading the entire User node with every single one of the users listed there, unless a username is actually being found in some of the users node. Is that correct? PS: This is the easy part of the Firebase Structure, I think I'll have to post another question for the more complicated stuff.

Comment: @Dani When createUser is called, it will supply to things to the completion block: *user, error*. If createUser was successful, the FIRUser will be returned in the block with the uid etc. If createUser fails, error will be populated indicating why it failed - one of those errors would be user name in use FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse. At that point you ask the user to use a different user name. Do NOT 'scan' the database to see if the new user name is in use, there's no need to. Just rely on create user to indicate that. If the answer helps, be sure to accept it so it can help others!